# Fetching columns by value on two pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the two following dataframes:

**df1**

```
        rate   amount            datetime  Loc
1    14.8000   293976 2020-08-09 16:00:00  136
2    15.0000  1205745 2020-08-09 16:00:00  136
3    13.4000   249321 2020-08-09 16:00:00  136
4    13.0000   376737 2020-08-09 16:00:00  136
5    14.5000   224181 2020-08-09 20:00:00  137
6    14.8000   300443 2020-08-09 20:00:00  137
7    15.0000  1184055 2020-08-09 20:00:00  137
```

**df2**

```
               Date     Open     High      Low    Close  Loc
2020-08-09 00:00:00  12.7396  12.9097  12.4076  12.6492  136
2020-08-09 04:00:00  12.6515  13.7592  12.5184  13.5465  137
```

I need to add two columns to `df1`, called `df1['Close']` and `df1['Open']`, and the value of these two values must be the value of the row in `df2` that has the same `Loc`.

So in this case the output should be:

```
        rate   amount            datetime  Loc     Open  Close
1    14.8000   293976 2020-08-09 16:00:00  136  12.7396  12.6492 
2    15.0000  1205745 2020-08-09 16:00:00  136  12.7396  12.6492 
3    13.4000   249321 2020-08-09 16:00:00  136  12.7396  12.6492 
4    13.0000   376737 2020-08-09 16:00:00  136  12.7396  12.6492 
5    14.5000   224181 2020-08-09 20:00:00  137  12.6515  13.5465 
6    14.8000   300443 2020-08-09 20:00:00  137  12.6515  13.5465 
7    15.0000  1184055 2020-08-09 20:00:00  137  12.6515  13.5465
```

Is there any way to do this, maybe with list comprehension? I've been looking into JOIN operations, but i'm not sure it's what i need here, since i don't need to fetch elements that the two dataframes have in common.

Comment: For you merge not working? What code failed?

Comment: Use `df = df1.merge(df2[['Loc','Open','Close']], on='Loc', how='left')`

Comment: Thank you a lot! Yes, i was wrong, i needed to join the dataframes